# Active in Passive

Tags: grammar

Hello can someone help me?

I am trying to make this sentence in passive form.
"People will always remember Walt Disney for his amazing creativity"

So should it be
"Walt Disney will be remembered for his amazing creativity"
or
"Walt Disney will always be remembered for his amazing creativity by people"?

If i didnt list correct answer could you write me the correct one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either revised example is fine, but the second might be improved:

- "Walt Disney will always be remembered by people for his amazing creativity."

In the first example, 'people' is implied, since only people are likely to remember Walt Disney for his creativity.

Comment: Yes. "By people" is not really necessary. Unless you went on to say that he will not be remembered by dogs or by Martians, it would seem that "people" are the only ones under discussion here. Specifying "by X" would make sense if you said what people will remember him. Like, "will always be remembered by visitors to his parks" or "will always be remembered by film makers" or whatever.